# (Qt) Cannot set font on widget

Tags: c++, qt, view, model, widget

well, I have defined two similar editor widgets LibroBancoEditor and ChequesEditor, they are used to input data to a database using the model/view framework.

After setting up the model and then the view on both widgets constructor comes the following:

```
view->setModel(proxy);//using a proxymodel to aling center items, shoud not affect the behavour
QFont font("Calibri", 12);
view->setFont(font);
view->resizeColumnsToContents();
```

The problem is: opening the program only cheques has the font I selected (libroBanco doesn't). Cannot fix it. I have tried changing the place of the calling but there was no results.

Here is a piece of the constructor of the main window...

```
    libroBanco = new LibroBancoEditor("Libro_Banco");
    cheques = new ChequesEditor("Cheques");


    connect(cheques,SIGNAL(printed(QSqlRecord)),libroBanco,SLOT(recivePrinted(QSqlRecord)));


    tabs = new QTabWidget();

    tabs->addTab(cheques,"Imprimir cheques");
    tabs->addTab(libroBanco,"Libro Banco");

    setCentralWidget(tabs);

    QFont font("Calibri", 12);
    setFont(font);
}
```

Any idea what could be causing the problem?

Comment: PS: Everything works fine except that.

Comment: I am also new to Qt but I have had succes doing it this way(even though it seems to be the same pretty much)

`view.setFont(QFont("Calibri",12));`

Comment: Did no changes... It's a very strange behaviour... I have read the code lot's of times, can't find the mistake.